# Kronecker delta in inertial tensor

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, notation, tensor-calculus

I feel confused in (11.9) how does the book prove the following identity:

$$\sum\limits_{i} w_{i}x_{\alpha,i}  \sum\limits_{j} w_{j}x_{\alpha,j} = \sum\limits_{i,j}w_{i}w_{j}x_{\alpha,i}x_{\alpha,j}$$

[image]

I tried to derive it myself:

$$\sum\limits_{i} w_{i}x_{\alpha,i} \sum\limits_{j} w_{j}x_{\alpha,j}   =  \sum\limits_{i}\sum\limits_{k}w_{k}\delta_{ik}x_{\alpha,i}   \sum\limits_{j}\sum\limits_{m}w_{m}\delta_{jm}x_{\alpha,j} $$

Exactly from here, I got stuck, but I'm still not very much convincing about the result that the book got, becasuse it does not contain kroncker delta function for the part I tried to derive.

Can anyone give me a mathematical proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kronecker delta is used in the first term, not the second.  In the first term, replace $\sum\limits_i \omega_i^2$ with $\sum\limits_{i,j}\omega_i\omega_j\delta_{ij}$.

For the second term, rearranging the summations is a pretty common thing to do.  The identity that you are interested in is essentially the distributive property.  As a simple example,
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^2 x_i \sum\limits_{j=1}^2 y_j
= (x_1+x_2)(y_1+y_2) = x_1(y_1+y_2)+x_2(y_1+y_2)
=\sum\limits_{i=1}^2 \sum\limits_{j=1}^2 x_i y_j
$$

Hope this helps.

---

**Edit:** I initially misread the OP's question.  I have updated my post to be more direct and relevant to the question asked.

Comment: Thanks! I was just confused with the distributive identity of the summation.